# Use "For Each" statement from the last element in a list to the first

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

When I want to iterate from the last element in a list to the first one, I usually do like this:

```
For i=list.Count-1 to 0 Step -1
    'do something
Next
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use the For Each statement iterating through the list this way.

Thanks!

Comment: This should not be easily possible as .NET uses the lists iterator to iterate over the list. I am not sure though, if it is possible to change the iterators behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with [Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx). If `list` is typed as `IEnumerable`, you can call it like this:

```
For Each item in list.Reverse()
Next
```

However if it is `ArrayList` or `List(Of T)`, this will call the [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) method which modifies the list (and doesn't return anything). In that case you could call from `Enumerable` directly or use [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx):

```
For Each item in Enumerable.Reverse(list)
Next

For Each item in list.AsEnumerable().Reverse()
Next
```

Something to be aware of is that this method will copy the list to an array. If you need to save memory, it would be better to use the `For...To` method. You could wrap this into your own [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) function [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) though:

```
<Extension()>
Public Iterator Function LazyReverse(Of T)(source As IList(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For i = source.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Yield source.Item(i)
    Next
End Function
```

Then call it any time like:

```
For Each item in list.LazyReverse()
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the overhead it creates, you could use reverse :

```
list.reverse()
for each listElement in list
' ...
next
```

Comment: Hehehe, nice, but I think it offuscates the code more than it clarifies it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If your list is a `List(Of T)` object, you can use it's `Reverse` method, for instance:

```
list.Reverse()
For Each i In list
    'do something
Next
```

However, that will alter the actual order of the items in the list.  If you want to get the items in the reversed order without affecting the order in the original list, you can use the `Reverse` extension method provided in LINQ, for instance:

```
For Each i In list.As Enumerable().Reverse()
    'do something
Next
```

The most efficient method, however, is to use `Step -1`, though it does mean more typing...